# Codename one wi-fi detection

Tags: android-wifi, codenameone

Im working with "Codename one" (Android developer) and I would like to know how can I detect if the phone has wi-fi activated or not. In this way, I can decide store data locally, and transmit it only when WI-FI is active. Otherwise, if I want to send pictures, without WI-FI, could be very expensive.

As a related question, do I have to setup some kind of cron or similar (in my code) in order to ask to my device if the WI-FI has been turned on?

Thank you very much for your help.

Kindly regards,
Gustavo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally to detect network you will need to use a check of whether you can connect to a specific server since a WiFi might be an airport wifi or something where you aren't authorized to connect outside. This will make it seem like wifi is connected but won't really work.

We have an APN API that allows you to detect the connection type (wifi/3g etc.) but it only works on Android/Blackberry and thus won't work (at this time) on iOS etc. Look at `NetworkManager` specifically: `isAPSupported`, `getCurrentAccessPoint`, `getAPType`.